# Why won't my last method printed? How can I get it to execute

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to get my last method executed, but I am unsure what I need to add to get that method into my main method. Currently my program executes the first method, then the second, and then the program ends. I am very new to java and any insight would be so helpful! Thank you for looking at my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dot {
    static int n = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getArrayOne();
        getArrayTwo();

    }

    public static double[] getArrayOne() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of your first vector :");
        int lengthOne = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        double[] vOne = new double[lengthOne];
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOne; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a vector value of your first vector :");
            double valuesOne = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
            vOne[i] = valuesOne;
        }
        System.out.println("Your first vector values are: " + Arrays.toString(vOne));
        return vOne;

    }

    public static double[] getArrayTwo() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of your second vector :");
        int lengthTwo = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        double[] vTwo = new double[lengthTwo];
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthTwo; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a vector value :");
            double valuesTwo = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
            vTwo[i] = valuesTwo;
        }
        System.out.println("Your second vector values are: " + Arrays.toString(vTwo));
        return vTwo;
    }

    public static double dotProduct(double vOne[], double vTwo[]) {
        double product = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            product = product + vOne[i] * vTwo[i];

        }
        System.out.println("Dot Product: ");
        System.out.println(dotProduct(vOne, vTwo));
        System.out.println(product);
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods `getArrayOne` and `getArrayTwo` are the same. What about if you want to`getArray2000`? Try to avoid multiplication of your code! Isn't enough to write the method `getAnyArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code in your main method to

```
double[] arr1 = getArrayOne();
double[] arr2 = getArrayTwo();
double dotProduct = dotProduct(arr1, arr2);
```

The problem is you don't actually call your `dotProduct` method.

Aside from this, there are some other things worth mentioning in your code.

1. You can eliminate some redundancy with a bit of refactoring. If you change your logic to have a generic `getArray(int, Scanner)`. This will help you keep your code more maintainable. The `int` type parameter will take the length of the array and the `Scanner` is the scanner you're using to get the input from the keyboard. Since you are doing a dot / scalar product, the vectors have to have the same length.
2. You need to close the `Scanner` object(s) you create in order to prevent memory leaks.
3. Your dotProduct method calls itself with no base case (uncontrolled recursion). That's a bad idea.

Consider the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the vectors whose dot product you wish to calculate :");
    int length = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Getting values for the first vector");
    double[] arr1 = getArray(length, scan);

    System.out.println("Getting values for the second vector");
    double[] arr2 = getArray(length, scan);

    System.out.println("Calculating the dot product");
    double dotProduct = getDotProduct(arr1, arr2);

    // TODO do something with the dot product

    scan.close();
}

private static double[] getArray(int length, Scanner scan) {

    double[] vector = new double[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a vector value :");
        double valuesOne = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
        vector[i] = valuesOne;
    }
    System.out.println("Your vector values are: " + Arrays.toString(vector));

    return vector;
}

private static double getDotProduct(double vOne[], double vTwo[]) {
    double product = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vOne.length; i++) {
        product = product + vOne[i] * vTwo[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Dot Product: ");
    System.out.println(product);
    return product;
}
```

Another thing worth reading would be the coding conventions for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the third method passing the return values of the first two methods

```
double[] array1 = getArrayOne();
double[] array2 = getArrayTwo();
double dotProduct = dotProduct(array1, array2);
```

*Some Notes for improving your current code:*

1. `getArrayOne` and `getArrayTwo` do the same work. So, you can combine them into one function and call it from main.
2. Don't need to create more than one `Scanner` object.

Comment: How would it be saved as two different variables? Would I assign two different variables to scan in one loop?

Comment: You create a new array object each time you call the function to input numbers